# Is it possible to render XNA game over camera preview in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, xna-4.0, augmented-reality

I have a demo working where I can render some text over a camera preview in windows phone 8, I now want to extend the app to render xna game content in an augmented reality style over camera preview.

Is this even possible with XNA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible

In fact, we are doing it for a game we are making

[Check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202984%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
and also 
[This](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx)